# Download file from DataGridViewLinkColumn stored as byte data in SQL Database - Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I am making a windows form Application, I use OpenFileDialog to store my data inside an SQL Database as bytes. I have included the code- Fill data shows the data on DataGridViewLink Columns, and button2_click(Browse and Save button) function stores it in the SQL Database.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult res = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (res == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            byte[] documentContent = File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            string name = fi.Name;
            string extn = fi.Extension;
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(LOC))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SaveDocument", cn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Content", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = documentContent;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Extn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = extn;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 2018;

                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            FillData();

        }
    }

    private void FillData()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(LOC))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetDocuments", cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "2018";
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            dt.Load(reader);
        }
        if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn colu in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                if (colu.HeaderText != "Name")
                    colu.Visible = false;
            }
        }

    }

    private void ITDec2018_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewLinkColumn col = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
        col.DataPropertyName = "DName";
        col.Name = "Name";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
        FillData();
    }
```

F.Y.I: I create my own table column for just the name and hide the other columns. DName is the Name of file in the database

I want to click on the link of the file, which is just the name with the link and the program should download the file associated with the ID of the file and store it in the downloads, or open the dialog box and ask me where to store it, I have included the screenshot of the display while running the application, as well as the SQL Database Table.

[SQL Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVVCh.jpg)

[Form with datagridViewLink Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwEq3.png)

So how should I do what is asked, should I update the cell content_click function and if so, how?

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
     }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the dataGridView1_CellContentClick does it give you something to link it with the SQL? like unique ID or something? If so then make a request to the SQL and grab the datafield and get get it as byte array like this 'byte[] byteArray = (byte[])row["datafieldName"];' then you can do whatever you like with this byte array, store it, modify it as you please.... PS. You can write it to file with File.WriteAllBytes Method (String, Byte[])

Comment: I'm new to SQL so I dont know what it gives me, when i double click the datagridviewtable in the definition it creates that function, so I'm not sure exactly what to do with it or what it gives us. Everything I wrote is I have included. Can you give a form of psuedo code or something

Comment: is Name in sql table unique? are there multiple entries with the same name?

Comment: id is unique, Name can be same; ID is primary key

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add the ID also into the datagridview and use this code, by replacing your connection and fixing the SQL query to your database name

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        string id = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

        string sqlQuery = string.Format("SELECT DocumentContent,DBName FROM myDatabase WHERE ID={0};", id);

        SqlDataAdapter myAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, myConnection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        myAdapter1.Fill(dt);

        Stream myStream;
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;


        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            byte[] byteArray = (byte[])row["DocumentContent"];
            string name = (string)row["DBName"];
            saveFileDialog1.FileName = name;
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                 if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                 {
                      myStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                      myStream.Close();
                 }
             }

            //File.WriteAllBytes("Path\\" + name, byteArray);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I added the code you gave me and the ID table. Wen it reaches the File.WriteAllBytes function it gives me this error: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path C:\Users\GursahejG\source\repos\Debug\Path\forst.jpg                    and by DBName you meant Dname, right? I thought it would open a save dialog window or something to choose where to save the file

Comment: @GursahejSingh Yes I mean DName, the File.WriteAllBytes was writing in a fixed path which you can change, I updated the code to use Save File Dialog.

Comment: But i just checked it, for some reason it is saying the file is currupted after  I Download and save it, i dont understand

Comment: For example when i open a PDF file, it says "There was an error opening this document, the file is damaged and could not be repaired. " The jpg files are only opening half, as in the bottom half is currupted